# Existence of function $f$ such that $f(x) \sim \sum_{j \in \mathbb{N}} x^{1 - \frac{1}{j}}$

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

Is there a function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$ such that as $x \to 0$,

$$
f(x) = \sum_{j=0}^N x^{1 - \frac{1}{j}} + o(x^{1- \frac{1}{N}}),
$$

for every $N \in \mathbb{N}$?
Heuristically there shouldn't be such a function, since the exponents accumulate at $1$ and thus higher terms are not "asymptotically independent", giving too much freedom in the choice of the coefficients in the sum, but I don't know how to even approach a proof.
It should be noted that if the exponents go to infinity, a modification of Borel's lemma holds yielding existence of such $f$.

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding your question, you can just choose a sequence of values $x_n$ and define $f(x)$ to be the $n$th partial sum in your expression between $x_n$ and $x_{n+1}$. As long as $x_n$ go to zero sufficiently quickly (for example $x_n = 10^{-n^2}$) the function will have limit 1 at $x=0$ and satisfy your little-o condition

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, $\sum_{j=0}^N x^{1-1/j}$ is undefined, since $1/0$ is undefined. So, let us use $\sum_{j=1}^N x^{1-1/j}$ instead.

For $x>0$, let
$$f(x):=\sum_{j=1}^\infty x^{1-1/j}1(x<e^{-j})=\sum_{1\le j<\ln(1/x)} x^{1-1/j}.$$
Then for each natural $N$ and small enough $x\in(0,1)$
$$0\le f(x)-\sum_{j=1}^N x^{1-1/j}=\sum_{N+1\le j<\ln(1/x)} x^{1-1/j}
\le x^{1-1/(N+1)}\ln(1/x)=o(x^{1-1/N})$$
as $x\downarrow0$, as desired.

Comment: It is easy to smoothen this function if necessary.

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov : That's right -- we can just smooth the indicators $1(\cdot<e^{-j})$ appropriately.